# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi'

Tags: c#, forms, database-connection

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title and I just can't seem get passed this.

Here is my code:

```
strSig = sigPlusNET1.GetKeyReceiptAscii()

            sigPlusNET1.LCDRefresh(1, 210, 3, 14, 14); 

            if (sigPlusNET1.NumberOfTabletPoints() > 0)
            {
                sigPlusNET1.LCDRefresh(0, 0, 0, 240, 64);
                Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
                sigPlusNET1.LCDWriteString(0, 2, 35, 25, f, "Semnatura a fost salvata.");
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO cstmae_Signatures(Signature)values("+ strSig +")", connection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
```

This is a standard Forms app.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried converting the strSig to Int32 and nothing, the type now is an 8 bit int that is beeing sent, but the problem is something with the sql connection.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi'."

```
query = "UPDATE dbo.History SET Volume = @Volume WHERE Symbol = @Symbol AND [start] = @Date; ";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                    {
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Symbol", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ti.Symbol;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ti.Date;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Volume ", SqlDbType.Float).Value = ti?.Volume;
try
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (System.InvalidCastException e)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }

                        con.Close();
}
```

Nothing is saved to the database and the only way to get the message is through the "non public members" of the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() method. When I check the parameters values there are all there and correct.

Comment: How does that answer the question?